# Question about VLR in vector.dev about iterating in array

Tags: vector, datadog

I have two questions:

1.
I have such block in json:

```
"meta":
    {
        "resource-spec-hash": "1111111111",
        "random.container.name": "vector",
        "random.resource.kind": "ReplicaSet",
        "random.resource.name": "vector-1111111111",
        "random.resource.namespace": "test"
    },
```

random - everytime is diffrent, so I can't remap this json simple by vlr like .name = del(random.container.name)
As I understand, I should iterate through meta, find string with "container.name" and get value of this string
How can I do this?

because if I use "for_each" func and give array on input - transform fails with error that it wait array and receive strings in it

2.
I have block:

```
"vulns" :
[
{},{},{},{},{}...
]
```

All {} the same inside, example:

```
"vulns":
[
{
"staticVar": {"randomVar1": {"staticVar2": "", "staticVar3": ""}, randomVar"2: ***, randomVarN": ***}
},
{
*same*
},
{
*same*
}
]
```

All randomVar in previous example consist this: {"staticVar2": "", "staticVar3": ""}, how I can delete staticVar3 ?

I was trying to use for_loop for both of this tasks, but vector says this about "for":
`this identifier name is reserved for future use in the language`

And another try:

map_keys and have a lot of errors from "wrong type in input" to "wrong type to output"

I'm just want to fill .name variable by the name of key with random part